# Kendo Grid Header Name

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need Kendo UI Grid column Headers like Name, Father Name, Date of Birth in jQuery alert 
in html button click event. Please Help me. Am new of the concepts.

Example Kendo Grid :

S.No    Name    Father Name Date of Birth
1   Kumar   Raja             15-8-1987

Comment: You are not providing enough information. Where are those buttons? Why you are not able to know the name of the column headers?

Comment: I have one button in html out of grid. I have bind the grid data dynamically (i.e., Auto bind) from database (Select * From table Name). Now I need in button click event I need the grid header column names.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't know the name of the columns? Something like that you have the same service for several `SELECT` and therefore you don't know the columns being received? If that's the case there are some question in StackOverflow for "dynamically generated columns" did you try them. Which is the format of the JSON received from the server? Can you add it to the original question?

Comment: Yes. I Don't know the column name. after bind the data I need the column header name on button click event.

Comment: Please, show us the JSON so we can provide some code closer to what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
var columns = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").columns;

if(columns.length > 0)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        var col =  columns[i];
        alert('Datasource field name' + col.field);
        alert('Column header name' + col.title);
    }
}
```

Please write above code snippet inside button click event.